# Problem with DevExtreme and angular testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, devexpress, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I'm developing some unit tests in Angular for one of my components and I'm having the following problem:

```
Failed: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'dx-data-grid'.
```

- If `dx-data-grid` is an Angular component and it has `dataSource` input, then verify that it is part of this module.
- If `dx-data-grid` is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

it seems to be a bug of some dependency, can someone help me with this?
Thank you.

Comment: You have to import the devexpress grid module to your component module.

Comment: My component works fine, I think the problem is that I have to import that module into my component.spec.ts, but I'm not sure how to do it, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The error tries to tell you that you need to add the missing component or module to the testing module. On the Angular homepage there is a nice introduction to unit testing, best go through this once to see how to set up the TestBed: https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-basics

Great that you start testing!

Comment: I am trying to test a component that seems to have many dependencies on others and it is doing something really complex for me, I am not sure how to handle this situation

Comment: Too many dependencies is usually a sign that the structure of that part of the app could be improved. But I guess you know that and testing the logic before a refactoring is anyhow a good idea. If there are many dependencies, there is basically no other way than going through adding/mocking all of them... You could use a library like [ngMocks](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/) to assist you. With that you can e.g. mock complete modules, or mock components so that you will at least not have to add dependencies of dependencies that are not interesting for your test case.